# Efficient creation of List<MyObject> with large amount of items

Tags: c#, optimization, c#-2.0

In my code I sometimes need to create large collections of objects. Please note that I need collections and not arrays, because I might need to add items later.

What is an efficient way to do this?

Let's assume that objects are quite simple and can be created fast with default parameter-less constructor. Something like this:

```
class MyObject
{
    private int a;

    public int A
    {
        get { return a; }
        set { a = value; }
    }
}
```

Sure, I can create my collection like this:

```
List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>(knownNumberOfItems);
for (int i = 0; i < knownNumberOfItems; i++)
    list.Add(new MyObject());
```

But maybe there is a better way to do the same?

**Summary from the discussion:**

- There is no faster way to do this for reference types. You might get some performance improvements using value types.
- Try allocating more space initially to reduce number of reallocations when new items are added later.

Comment: If it fits the requirements, consider making MyObject a struct. That would shave off some overhead

Comment: Just FYI, List<T> is backed by an array.  You have stated you don't want to use an array because of performance concerns.  Using List<T> instead of an array will not alleviate this problem because List<T> in turn will use an array itself under the hood.

Comment: @Dejas I guess I can't do anything about reallocations of the underlying array. But I just don't want to do these reallocations myself.

Comment: You wont have to do the reallocations yourself.  But you will take the performance hit.  Unless you only ever add known_number_of_items, in which case no reallocation will ever occur.  I'm still unsure as to whether you mean known_number_of_items to be an upper bound on the number of adds.  This is the critical issues from a performance perspective.

Comment: @Dejas knownNumberOfItems is an initial amount. In most cases some items will be added later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no faster way that I'm familiar with. I'd personally use braces around the body of the `for` loop, but as a way of creating a list of a given size, populated with distinct references to new objects, that's about it. The important part is that you specified the size of the list to start with, so those `Add` calls won't need to reallocate anything internally.

If you're potentially going to add items later on, you *may* want to give a slightly bigger size, of course.

It feels unlikely that this is a bottleneck in your system though - and as always, readability should be your primary concern (and isn't an issue here other than the change I've suggested) with performance being constantly measured, but only causing change at a low level when a concern has been validated by measurements.

Comment: I think his point about not using arrays is that he knows he needs known_number_of_items now but will need to add some unknown number of objects in the future.

Comment: @Dejas: Yes, but he may have *some* idea about a likely distribution of "extra items to add". So for example, it may be worth adding an extra 10% in expectation of *some* additions.

Comment: I'm also use camelCasing. Underscores are used in the code snippet for extra emphasis only.

Comment: @Bobrovsky: Emphasis of what? It's a distraction more than emphasis, IMO. If your normal code is idiomatic/conventional, make your sample code idiomatic/conventional too :)

Comment: @JonSkeet ok, I've fixed the distracting underscores. Thanks for suggestion of adding extra 10% to initial capacity of the list. In most cases I think it's an adequate amount. I will do some test later, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Not in .Net 2.0. Starting with .Net 3.5, you can write it slightly shorter, but the compiled result will be basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your way is pretty efficient - an array is created with enough space for all your items, and list.Add is blazingly fast.

Are you experiencing a performance problem?

Comment: yes, I experience some problems with large collections (> 10 thousand items).

Comment: @Bobrovsky what problems, specifically?  What code appears to perform slowly?  Have you profiled?

Comment: @phoog yes, I did profile. There are number of problems in my code. I don't want to discuss all of them in one question. For this question I just wanted to know if I can speed up creation of large collections. I think I get some valuable advises.

Comment: @Bobrovsky fair enough.  The reason I asked is that I have worked on some code with large collections as well, and the performance problems were not particularly related to adding new items; they were more related to a lack of free memory.

Comment: @phoog that's another issue I have at my hands :-)

Comment: The only way you can create the collection faster, is to use an Array and keep track of the place to insert a new element yourself. You will save the check whether the array needs to be resized or not.

However, this check, run 10,000 times, should take a couple of microseconds, so I doubt you will gain anything from it. I'm pretty sure your problem is elsewhere. I would start looking at the creation of those 10,000 objects.

Answer (score 1):

I might consider looking at

```
LinkedList<T> list = ...
```

add operations to linked lists are constant time.

Comment: If the List<> is preallocated (as it is in his case), adding an item is done in constant time, and the constant is smaller than that of a LinkedList. Traversal is more efficient, too. For all practical purposes, he's using an array here.

Comment: @Dejas: If you know the size of the list in advance, the `List<T>` initialized with the size is constant time for add operations as well. In his example, he knew the size already.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but I need items in the collection to be accessible by an index.

Comment: Do you know prior to the creation of list the maximum number of items that could ever be added to the list?  If so, your current implementation is fine.  If not, consider LinkedList<T>.

Comment: @Dejas no, I don't know exact amount to be added later.

Answer (score 1):

Consider making your type a value type (`struct`) so that you don't need to allocate memory for instances and that your list will not fragment the memory. After that create the list like:

```
var List = new MyList<MyObject>(Enumerable<MyObject>.Repeat(new MyObject(),
                                known_number_of_items));
```

From its [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx), its guaranteed to run at `O(n)`. this will not work with reference type (`class`) however, as it will insert the same object over and over.

Comment: thank you for suggestion, but in my case the type can't be a value type.

Comment: @Bobrovsky: there is no way to create continuous expandable storage for objects in C#. I suggest switching to C++ if you can if this is a performance issue, because creating a huge amount of objects one by one will stress out the managed memory and garbage collector, while in C++ you can just use one continuous expandable container (std::vector)